# How to combine sql statements in ibatis?

Tags: mysql, sql, ibatis

I have the following statement, which I need in  order to update an entry in my database:

```
<update id="setAsDefault" >
  START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = FALSE WHERE owner = #{ownerId} AND is_default= TRUE;
    UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = TRUE  WHERE brand = #{brandId};
   COMMIT;
</update>
```

Both statements work individually. Also, they work when combined if I enter them manually in mysql. When I try to run this from ibatis however I get the following error:

```
### Error updating database.  Cause:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = FALSE WHERE owner = '123_test_user_' at line 2
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: START TRANSACTION;         UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = FALSE WHERE owner= ? AND is_default= TRUE;         UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = TRUE  WHERE brand = ?;        COMMIT;
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = FALSE WHERE owner = '123_test_user_' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` test statement is more clear:

```
<update id="setAsDefault" >
  START TRANSACTION;
  <if test="ownerId != null">
      UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = FALSE WHERE owner = #{ownerId} AND is_default= TRUE;
  </if>
  <if test="brandId != null">
      UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = TRUE  WHERE brand = #{brandId};
  </if>
   COMMIT;
</update>
```

Comment: I get the exact same error. I don't see how adding conditional statements would make a difference.

Comment: Show me the errors in detail? And the argument you pass the java method?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`UPDATE cms_wall SET is_default = IF(owner = #{ownerId} AND is_default=TRUE,FALSE,IF(brand = #{brandId},TRUE,is_default));`